# is it possible to install mssql with all terminal tools in kali linux

Tags: sql-server, kali-linux, multiarch

I have installed Kali Linux the previous year for learning purpose, but now I am in love with this Linux distro and vim, since I am a new user to linux, based on my knowledge I have tried all possible thing to install Microsoft SQL Server in Kali Linux, but I am unable to install, I have been https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ through this. I suppose Kali Linux is a debian(testing) based distro, so I tried to do it, but I am not seeing any improvement. Please, developer, help me with this

Comment: You can refer to this documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup?view=sql-server-ver15
An alternative solution to this is Docker! You can download Docker and pull the MSSQL image from the docker hub - https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server

Comment: Thank You so much, I have got the solution with in 6 hours... credit goes to all dev folks like you on stack overflow... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install Docker on it, right?  Then just use the [SQL Server Docker images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-docker-container-deployment?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-bash).

Comment: Thank You so much for you time. I didn't think of using docker, Let me use then revert back to you if it works or no.

Comment: Yes It worked, but with a slight tweak, I am using docker image inside vscode... that's making to somewhat easier to use... But still thanks for your answer